# Font Size forces Circle Button Wider

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a bit of a problem here.

I am using Ionic 3.

I have a circular button with a plus sign in it. When I increase the plus sign `font-size` up it forces the button wider [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI32n.png). I have tried setting `max-width` and `!important` and many other things but they don't do a thing.
[Here is what it looks like unscaled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRI35.png)

```css
.btnAddImage {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #4E4E4E;
  font-size: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div text-center>
  <button ion-button class="btnAddImage">+</button>
</div>
```

My Goal is to have a circular button with a large plus sign in it.

Cheers, zuke

Comment: Whats your goal? Circular button with a bigger plus sign?

Comment: Yep, @benni that's what I want

Comment: @zuke add a class name to div "text-center"

Comment: Probably because you have natural padding and borders on the button which are elongating it - try adding `box-sizing: border-box` to your button.  If that's not the problem, please can you make a [mcve] as the code you have provided seems to work fine (in chrome)

Comment: You can't go by the code snippet because I am using ionic. I am thinking maybe I should just use an image, ```box-sizing: border-box;``` did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
.text-center {
background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    color: #4E4E4E;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btnAddImage{
    font-size: 50px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It worked for the code snippet but I have a different problem. I am using ionic. Thanks for the try though!

Answer (score 1):

This works, just change the `class` name:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.circle::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: I just want to keep it simple and use text plus sign not create one out of css. Thanks though!